# css submenu keep flushing while website loads

Tags: java, jquery, css, menu

Some reasons i am experiencing this issue on my website.

When the website loads in, for a second the sub-menus are visible. If i go and click for any other menus there, the first i will see is again the sub-menus will be visible for a second.
I checked in Firefox,Chrome,safari everywhere is the same.

I have spent a lot of time ro resolve this issue but unfortunately i couldn't.
The page is here: http://myproperty-solution.co.uk/index.php

Could someone please have a look in to this for me?

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: just for the records, this issue is commonly reffered as FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, in your stylesheet just add this code

```
 .sf-menu ul { display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

all the other answers are good but incomplete - you should hide that only when javascript is on. when javascript is off, you should still display them.

so you should do something like this:

```
.js .sf-menu ul {
    display: none;
}
```

where `.js` is a class set on your body only when js is on, like this, in your `<head>`

```
<script>
<!-- 
    if (document.documentElement && document.getElementById){
        document.documentElement.className += " js";
    }
// -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style="display: none;" to your child menu ul's.

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li><a  href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <li><a href="?page=contactus">Contact us</a>
        <ul style="display: none;"> <!-- add style here -->
            <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that them menu script (superfish) is triggered on [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, which happens after all elements on a page are loaded. Currently, your submenu is visible until the ready event is fired.

Edit: as others have stated, the style should be added to CSS instead using the style attribute directly on the element.

Comment: Thank you, if I do, than it wont be visible at all.. I might put it in the woring place. Could you please direct me? I try to put the menu's css here:

Comment: It should be visible after superfish kicks in. Superfish controls the visibility of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should set them to `display:none` in the css, so that they are not visible as the page loads.

*Post the code for your css here, rather than send users to your website to fix it.*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you control menu using javascript, and javascript code works wwhen page is loaded. So for few moments your menu is using only css.

Try to add to css file

```
ul ul { display: none; }
```